# adding svg element on a node list gets applied only in last element on the loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I would add a `rect` on every first child of a node list.

I loop this list and add a rectangle every time

What is happening is that the rect is getting added only on the last element of the loop.

```
let rect : NodeList = this.synoptic.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("#stops g");
let rect2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','rect');
rect2.setAttribute("fill","red");
rect2.setAttribute('x', '0');
rect2.setAttribute('y', '0');
rect2.setAttribute('height', '50');
rect2.setAttribute('width', '50');
rect.forEach((elm : Node) => {
  elm.insertBefore(rect2,elm.firstChild);
  console.log(elm)
})
```

Here an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wgbws?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: yes, you're moving `rect2` around, `elm` by `elm`. If you want one rect per elm, you need to create one rect per elm. And not one for all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)